# MSMQ: incoming traffic, but messages don't show up in the queue

Tags: msmq, message-queue

I'm transferring our web application to new infrastructure and I'm stuck at the MSMQ part.

1st screenshot: Server A sends messages to server B. I see the outgoing messages appear on server A.
2nd screenshot: Server B shows incoming traffic, but the messages don't appear in the queue.

The service picking up the messages at server B is not running!

Any ideas how to debug this situation?

[image: Server A sends messages to server B. I see the outgoing messages appear on server A.]
[image: Server B shows incoming traffic, but the messages don't appear in the queue.]

Answer (score 1):

The status of the outgoing queue is connected but the messages aren't moving. Likely to be that the acknowledgement messages are not being sent back successfully from server B. As server A never sees the acknowledgements, it is stuck in a permanent state of retrying to send awaiting a response.

There should be an outgoing queue on server B pointing back to server A. Check its status.  It is very likely that the IP address of the outgoing queue is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If the messages are queuing in your outgoing queue on server A that means that they are definitely not being sent to the destination queue on server B.

If you have messages arriving on server B but not being delivered then this is probably due to queue permissions. However, based on your assertion that messages queue up on the outbound queue I can't see how server B can be receiving any messages.